# Looking for a GSM modem advice

Tags: windows, device, gsm

My application communicates with several GSM electric controllers, that means that I have to send anywhere between one to twenty messages every few hours. right now I'm working with **HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G**. it is a USB device that uses a comm port for the pc communication and  I'm using [GSMComm](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm) to send messages and read/delete messages from the device.

Every two seconds I'm checking the device's storage, and if there is any message, I will then read it and store it locally and then clear the device's storage. I'm not sure if I'm working correctly, but it seems to me as if it is a very unreliable device:

Every time I boot my machine, I must remove the device from the USB or my machine will get stuck at the BIOS start up screen (or whatever the name is).

Very frequently the comm port can become unavailable for some reason. I have to close and re open the port, and at times that may not even help.

In the production machine of my client, when he uses one of his software's that utilize the first comm port, he will get a warning message from the software about problems in the port if the device is plugged in (the device port is around 28 or something).

If you've been using a device which you consider reliable, or have been working with the same device as I work with, or you just think that I'm doing it wrong, I'd like to get an advice from you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with your modem.  Have you tried any other models?  Consumer USB models tend to be unreliable.  The preferred method, though slightly more expensive, is using a commercial grade modem in situations where you need the reliability.

Some modems to look at:

- Wavecom Fastrack
- Sierra Wireless Airlink

These use a serial port or ethernet to communicate with the host which is far more reliable.  Serial ports may not be available in your particular situation but even a USB to RS232 adapter will be more reliable.

One further option is to use a smartphone, there are several applications that you can act as a gateway through HTTP.

SMS Gateway for Android:

https://market.android.com/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway&hl=en

i have not used this method, but it seems like some people are having luck with it.  it may not be any more reliable then your USB modem though.

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

I have used WaveCom's modem for sending messages in bulks and found it to be reliable. One difference though, in my implementation was i used Kannel as an SMSC, so my queues were automatically handled by Kannel. But sending multiple requests like 40+ per minute didnt pose any problems for me. 
Hope this helps.